# SQL Trigger for any table modification on the db

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm new to triggers. I would like to know **how to write a trigger** for insert a log record to a table called LogReportTable, **when the any update,insert or delete in any table inside the database**. 
(purpose of this requirement is to secure database from unauthorized modification)
Please help. thank you. :)

Comment: Are you on enterprise edition of SQL Server perhaps?

Comment: It will audit not secure.  Just put a trigger on every table.  I think you are going to need to hard code the table name anyway.  This will get the user  convert(nvarchar(100), SYSTEM_USER).

Comment: @dean : I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Standard or Enterprise edition?

Comment: It's Enterprise. 
(Can I use Audit to achieve my requirement ? then how ?)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create an After insert trigger for this purpose, But you cannot create this trigger on database level.

Since this trigger will response to a DML action (insert) it will be a DML After Insert Trigger and you will need to create a trigger for each table you want to log information for.
It is the DDL Trigger which has DATABASE Scope not DML Triggers.

You should avoid using triggers whenever possible as they are kind of Silent Killers :S

If Database Audit is the only purpose I think you are better off looking into [`Change Data Capture`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

OR [`Change Tracking`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (Advised by Mr. Dean) if anything goes wrong you can sue him :)

Comment: What do you mean by "Silent Killers" ,Is there any disadvantage in Tiggers ? I gotta problem with outside data modification. Someone has modified the data, but I couldn't catch that unauthorized intruder. But if i can do something i asked in the above question, then i can track the user. PLEASE HELP.. :(

Comment: By Silent Killers I meant, Triggers fire in response to actions its not something we control directly, Once when you have created a trigger on something, you might forget that you have a trigger on that table but later on you do something that conflicts the trigger definition and if can be really confusing when you are doing everything right but something keeps messing up things for you, (The triggers firing). So it can be a bit of pain sometimes.

Comment: @M.Ali But CDC won't help OP to "catch that unauthorized intruder".

Comment: Neither would Triggers help against "unauthorized intruder". But with CDC a little bit of tweaking can log information about the users.

Comment: @M.Ali Agreed on triggers, of course. But if OP's on EntEd (should be for CDC), then he'd be better off to use auditing instead of CDC, or CT.

Comment: Sir I am not too sure about the availability of these features in different editions. Yes agreed CT will be a better option.

Comment: @dean Watch out for any Sue claims coming your way :)